# Buildfire: Hide Back Button and Customize Title Bar

Tags: buildfire

I am trying to hide the back button and customize the title bar to accept a logo.
window.parent is being blocked.

Comment: THat definitely wont work there are security measures to stop that. Your best bet is to hide it completely with buildfire.appearance.titlebar.hide()
 and create your own

Comment: Is there any way to hide the title bar while navigating between plugins?  The title bar still exists while the next plugin is loading, even as the first line in the index.html

Comment: To my knowledge no. The problem with turning it off is that all other plugins lose navigation input.